# Uncaught TypeError when calling outerArray[index].innerArray[outerArray[index].innerArray.length].foo

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, object, syntax

I have this code:

```
var outerArray = new Array();
func1();

function func1() {

    outerArray[0] = new Array();
    outerArray[0].innerArray = new Array();
    func2(0);
}

function func2(index) {

    outerArray[index].innerArray[outerArray[index].innerArray.length].foo = 3;
    console.log(outerArray[index].innerArray[outerArray[index].innerArray.length].foo);
}
```

The code gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'foo' of undefined
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some debugging and have found the following observations,

you do initialize your `outerArray[0].innerArray` but you don't have any element in it.

so `outerArray[0].innerArray.length` which is `0` would be the index for your statement `outerArray[0].innrerArray[outerArray[index].innerArray.length]`

but the array `outerArray[0].innerArray` is empty. so this statement `outerArray[0].innerArray[0]` returns an `undefined`